# jMeter .jmx to corresponding java code

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, jmx, jmeter-plugins, web-api-testing

We can generate JMeter .jmx files from JMeter Java APIs.

Is there any way via which we can convert per-recorded .jmx file into corresponding java code?

This can be useful for comparing changes between jmx files versions.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is quite old question, you might want to try JMeter DSL jmx2dsl tool: https://abstracta.github.io/jmeter-java-dsl/guide/#dsl-code-generation-from-jmx-file

Answer (score 0):

As of today (October 2018) there is no such tool and I doubt there will be as the JMeter XML is not really a contract and building a tool on it would be very fragile.

XML is not supposed to be used when using XML, the GUI is the way to use JMeter for scripting and the CLI (NON GUI mode) for load testing.